# insert to hidden field array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

I have:

```
<form id="postform" action="order_total.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="post_data[]" id="post_data" value="">
</form>
```

in some javascript function I filling an array like this:

```
var postdata = [];
var article = [];
article.push('a','b','c');  
postdata.push(article);
article = [];
article.push('a','b','c');  
postdata.push(article);
article = [];
article.push('a','b','c');  
postdata.push(article);
```

and after this I do like this:

```
$("#post_data").val(postdata);
$("#postform").submit();
```

But 'postdata' looks like a string when I'm trying to show it in 'order_total.php':

```
Array ([0] => a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c)
```

but I need that this data posted as arrays:

```
Array ([0] => Array ([0] => a, [1] => b, [2] => c),
[1] => Array ([0] => a, [1] => b, [2] => c),
[2] => Array ([0] => a, [1] => b, [2] => c));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. with ajax it's good, but I need to post with redirect to this page.

Comment: The easiest I could think of is to use `Json.stringify()` on client, then use `json_decode()` in PHP (if you are using PHP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `postdata` is an Array (or Object), and you try to set it as a value in an input field like:

```
$("#post_data").val(postdata);
```

You will get unexpected behavior, since an input field’s value can typically only contain strings. The easiest (and safest) way to get around this is to stringify the object into JSON:

```
$("#post_data").val(JSON.stringify(postdata));
```

Then decode it again on the server or in a middleware.